# Stop Infinite Arraylist With Custom Command

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm a complete beginner doing some made up projects to teach myself Java. The goal for my script is to allow input into the arraylist until a given exit command is provided. the sc.next() is just left over form my last attempt but my Google-Fu hasn't led me to the answer on how to setup a custom exit command for the arraylist.

Looking for ideas to complete this mission.

```
int i = 0;
while (sc.Next()) {
    System.out.println("Respond end when done. Please enter dinner option #" + (i + 1));
    String answer = sc.nextLine();
    Dinner.add(answer);
    i++;
}

//Randomizing the arraylist to print output
Random r = new Random();
{
    int randomitem = r.nextInt(Dinner.size());
    String randomElement = Dinner.get(randomitem);
    System.out.println("Random Element = " + randomElement);
}
```

Example of output would be...

```
Respond end when done. Please enter dinner option #1
American
Respond end when done. Please enter dinner option #2
Chinese
Respond end when done. Please enter dinner option #3
Pizza
Respond end when done. Please enter dinner option #4
Thai
Respond end when done. Please enter dinner option #5
end
```

Goal is to enter "end" then it would move onto the randomizer that would output 1 of the arraylist items.

Comment: What do you mean by "Respond end when done"?

Comment: Hello and welcome. What you're trying to do is unclear. Please [edit] your question to include an example run (inputs and outputs) that you expect and what you're getting instead.

Comment: @ScottHunter This is just display text. The end goal is to issue "end" and it stops adding to the arraylist and moves onto the randomizer.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Just edited the post. Let me know if that still isn't clear.

Comment: So something like `if(answer.equals("end")) break;` before adding `answer` to the `ArrayList` should do the trick.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the while loop with different condition. Pseudo code example:

```
Scanner scanner = //init;
String answer = scanner.nextLine();
while(!answer.equals("end")) {
  //add to list
  answer = //read next input;
}
//do randomizing stuff
```